# Compare Column value with more than one in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have `test` table which is

[image]

this is my table i am comparing string and getting the `entity_id` from this table

my sql query for one value search is like this

```
 Select entity_id From test Where BINARY  value = '".$my_search_list."'
```

this works fine if i search for single value like `Shirt`

i want to search for multiple values and when i try it with Comma Separated value 
like  `Root,Appare,hand Bags` (more than work) it is not giving me output

i Also tried with this

```
Select entity_id From test Where BINARY  value IN ( '".$my_search_list."' )
```

i don't want multiple query i want to do it in single query is it possible???

Comment: You need a loop to match all keyword, in that way you can decide if is better to use `and` operator or `or` operator

Comment: @Fabio do you mean in PHP??? or in MySql??

Comment: In php, create an array of search keyword and loop in it creating query parts wich you will concatenate in a single one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i was thinking as i said is to create an array of keywords and see which one match the criteria then show all result.

```
$search = array('Root','Appare','hand Bags');
$sql = "SELECT `entity_id` FROM `test` WHERE ";
$count = 0;
$search_size = count($search);   

foreach($search as $key)
{
    $count++;
    if($count < $search_size)
    {
        $sql .= "(`value` = '".$key."') or ";
    } 
    else if ($count == $search_size)
    {
        $sql .= "(`value` = '".$key."')";
    }
}
```

is you echo `$sql` you will see the correct query wich should work:

```
SELECT `entity_id` FROM `test` WHERE (`value` = 'Root') or (`value` = 'Appare') or (`value` = 'hand Bags')`
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use quotes for values

```
SELECT entity_id FROM test WHERE value IN ('one','two','three')
```